# how to hide a button when there is only one input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have created a input type file for uploading site. also i created two button , one of them is for appending the input type file and another is for removing them, but i wanna to hide the delete button when i have only one input type file, these are my codes :

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.add').click(function (e) {
        $('.addon').append('<div class="choose"><input type="file" name="userFile" /></div>');
    });
    $('.delete').click(function (e) {
        $('.addon > .choose').last().remove();
        if ($('<div class="choose"><input type="file" name="userFile" /></div>').length == 1) {
            $('.delete').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            $('.delete').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
});
```

and the html

```
<div class="addon">
    <div class="choose">
        <input type="file" name="userFile" />
    </div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work, can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give the input a class

```
<input type="file" name="userFile" class="file" />
```

and then change your if statement to

```
if($('.file').length == 1){....
```

Comment: i don't thins this is solution because there is no problem with the input , i think it is for if and else.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you are asking, but it seems to me like you want the check for length to be triggered by the onChange event for your input element.

Answer (score 0):

Have your if condition as

```
 $('.delete').length > 1
```

Thats what you seem to be asking. And the HTML seems incomplete for this question